# How can I make my toilet flush with more force?

Tags: plumbing

How do I make my toilet flush stronger? The water in the tank is already maximum to top of overflow pipe.

Comment: Please revise your post to tell us something about your toilet. We don't even know what side of the planet you're on. so we can't assume. Also tell us about the age and type of your plumbing.

Comment: If you rapidly pour a large bucket of water into the bowl does it flush well?  This test helps you decide if the problem is in the drain or in the tank/bowl/flush mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the design of the toilet.

Over time, the holes that allow the water from the tank to the bowl can get clogged with minerals from the water.  You want to restore an open path for the best rush of water into the bowl.

This process works for the most common type of toilets that have a number of small holes under the rim of the bowl and also those that have just a few holes near the front of the bowl.

Clean the holes mechanically with small wire to un plug and break off the mineral deposits.

Flush after with the water to the tank turned off.  Add about a cup of calcium remover to the **tank**.(**not the bowl)** An example of the cleaner is [CLR](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07G9JMTS2)    (Use appropriate eye and skin protection)

Open the flapper valve to let the cleaner get to the bowl rim and further clean the holes. Let the cleaner sit an hour or longer if possible.

Turn the water to the tank back on. Flush a couple of times and you are done.

Comment: It's not just minerals that clog the bowl wash-down outlets. If the toilet has ever backed up due to a clog (especially one caused by a user's grossly excessive use of paper), the pulp from the dissolved paper can plug the holes.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is **more often the drain pipe and/or vent pipe being clogged**, or partially clogged. Clean those out and check for issues (such as sags in the line not draining correctly) before turning much attention to the toilet itself.

Answer (score -1):

The water comes out by gravity, so, I can think of three ways

- Get a better toilet
- Raise the cistern
- Get a bigger cistern

Comment: I would also check that the drain pipe and the vent pipe are clear of any clogs.

Comment: Also when I replaced my flooring I used a cheaper bare wax ring to remount the toilet rather than the type with the plastic centering obstruction. The flow has greatly improved.